# ¿Cómo ingreso una Ñ en un varchar?

Tags: oracle

En una base Oracle, tengo una tabla con campo definido como varchar(2), en el que debo ingresar un código (llave de la tabla), pero al ingresar el código 'LÑ' me devuelve un error, he usado Ñ en otro campo en la misma tabla.

La tabla solo tiene estos dos campos (En el campo DESCRIPTION, si puedo ingresar Ñ):

```
"PROFESSIONID" VARCHAR2(2), 
"DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(200),
```

La inserción la hago con este codigo

```
INSERT INTO ESQUEMA.TABLA (PROFESSIONID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('LÑ','ESTA ES LA DESCRIPCION');
```

El error que devuelve es el siguiente.

```
SQL Error [12899] [72000]: ORA-12899: el valor es demasiado grande para la columna "ESQUEMA"."TABLA"."PROFESSIONID" (real: 3, máximo: 2)
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? y ¿Porqué se presenta este error?

Comment: Creo que la ñ ocupa más de un char (son dos char), por eso LÑ es demasiado grande para meterlo en un campo char(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, según entiendo lo que muestra el error, el carácter "Ñ" lo entiende como **2 caracteres** (si buscas en tu propia base de datos, verás que la Ñ está comprendida como Ã±), mientras que la letra "L" o cualquier otra letra estándar del teclado lo entiende como solamente **1 carácter**.

(Por eso lo de `(real: 3, máximo: 2)` en tu error). Si quieres solucionarlo, lo más fácil es que aumentes el *VARCHAR* de 2 a 3, y no deberías tener problemas con añadir más Ñ, quedando así:

```
"PROFESSIONID" VARCHAR2(3),  "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(200),
```

La Ñ se guarda en la base de datos como "**Ã±**", de ahí que sean 2 caracteres y debas aumentarla para que te funcione correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias DarkIceDust. Me ayudó mucho. Deberé modificar las tablas que se relacionan con esta considerando que se deberá usar el varios procesos.

Saludos!

Comment: De nada! Me alegro que te ayudara. Exacto! Mucha suerte, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la ñ ocupa más de un char (son dos char), por eso LÑ es demasiado grande para meterlo en un campo char(2).

Tendrás que ampliar tu campo.